# Windows 10 mobile are not allowed to install APK now? (11-Sep-2016)

Tags: windows-10-mobile, android

Just want to make sure now windows 10 mobiles are no longer available to install APK in order to run Android apps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile will not run Android apps. The Project Astoria was discontinued.

There are some good reasons for it too.

- It reqiuired an Android subsystem within Windows devices which caused a lot of battery issues and performance downgrade
- These apps did not have native features such as Tiles, Interactive notifications, etc...
- The parallel project of porting iOS apps proved to be much better.
- The problem of pirate apps became real.
- Some developers began to think that creating apps for Android is enough as Windows can run apps.

Now imagine a lot of apps running just as in Android without Live tiles, Cortanan integration, Onedrive backups, Interactive notifications, etc... It would be the death of Windows Mobile.

**References :**

1. [Microsoft officially cancels Project Astoria](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-officially-cancels-project-astoria-bridge-porting-android-apps-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 mobile does't support APK.